# 入力したvalueを取得して表示したい

Tags: javascript, milkcocoa

```
<textarea name="" id="content" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="テスト"></textarea>   
 <input type="text" name="" id="name" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="名前">
```

上のように、2つのエリアから入力した情報を取得しようと考えています。

Jsの方は、

```
//3."message"データストアからメッセージを取ってくる
        ds.stream().sort("desc").next(function(err, datas) {
            datas.forEach(function(data) {
                renderMessage(data);
            });
        });

        //4."message"データストアのプッシュイベントを監視
        ds.on("push", function(e) {
            renderMessage(e);
        });

        var last_message = "dummy";

        function renderMessage(message) {
            var message_html = '<p class="post-text">' + escapeHTML(message.value.content) + '</p>';
            var date_html = '';
            if(message.value.date) {
                date_html = '<p class="post-date">'+escapeHTML( new Date(message.value.date).toLocaleString())+'</p>';
            }
            $("#"+last_message).before('<div id="'+message.id+'" class="post">'+message_html + date_html +'</div>');
            last_message = message.id;
        }
function post() {
            //5."message"データストアにメッセージをプッシュする
            var content = escapeHTML($("#content").val());
            var name = escapeHTML($("#name").val());
            if (content && content !== "") {
                ds.push({
                    title: "タイトル",
                    content: content,
                    name: name,
                    date: new Date().getTime()
                }, function (e) {});
            }
            $("#content").val("");
            $("#name").val("");
        }

        $('#post').click(function () {
            console.log(name);
            post();
        })
        $('#content').keydown(function (e) {
            if (e.which == 13){
                post();
                return false;
            }
        });
        $("#name").keydown(function (e) {
            if (e.which == 13){
                post();
                return false;
            }
        });
    });`
```

このようになっています。

postがクリックされた時に、contentは表示されるのですが、nameの方は表示されません。
データストアからどのような流れでcontentが取得されているのか分からないのですが、
nameはどのように記述すれば良いのでしょうか？

お願いします。

Answer (score 1):

表示されないのは表示していないからではないでしょうか。
renderMessage()にてmessage.value.nameを出力している箇所が見当たりませんが・・・

Comment: valueに値を入れることができました。

Comment: valueに値を入れるとは？なにを報告しているのでしょうか？